# Is it possible to use Kotlin smart cast in a generic function return type?

Tags: kotlin, generics

The following example gives a `expected R found String` compilation error. Is it possible to implement this pattern in Kotlin without adding casts? If it isn't possible it would be interesting to learn why Kotlin can't infer the return type in this example.

```
interface Command<R>

sealed class SomeCommand<R> : Command<R> {
    data class DoSomething(val someInput: Int) : SomeCommand<String>()
}

fun <R> processCommand(command: SomeCommand<R>) : R {
    return when (command) {
        is SomeCommand.DoSomething -> {
            "this does not work!" // :-(
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that `R` is `String`. And if it *is* the same as `String`, why bother with generics at all? You'll likely have to cast it. Also, it doesn't seem like a good idea to put `DoSomething` inside `SomeCommand`

Comment: I don't understand how `R` can by anything other then `String` after the `is SomeCommand.DoSomething` test

Comment: Unfortunately, you'll still have to cast to R

Comment: It's way too many steps of logic for the compiler to see that. You've boiled it down to something a human can check pretty quickly, but to handle it as generalized logic for functions that can have multiple parameters, subclasses that may or may not specify the type, types that may or may not be `open`, classes with multiple generic types, etc, the complexity explodes.

Comment: if Kotlin had first-class types, maybe you could do something like `if (R is String)`, but that's never going to happen

Comment: @user Isn't that about type erasure, not the lack of first-class types (which, as I understand it, Kotlin has)?  If `R` were `reified`, then that should work.

Comment: @gidds Reified types would certainly help, but you can hardly use types in expressions to check if they're equal even in inline functions

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Feels good to be able to stop wasting time trying to get this working :D

Comment: Scala can do this particular thing (search for something like "Scala GADT"). It's also a source of many bugs and confusion when something similar but not exactly that doesn't work, so I am not surprised Kotlin's developers opted out of supporting it :)

Comment: @user `if (R == String)` would make more sense in my opinion.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Sorry, I confused my syntax